# Axis Locator is being ignored when the all values are lower than 2

Tags: python, matplotlib, ticker

I have been using this code:

```
  loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=1)        
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(loc)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))
    ax.grid(axis='y', which='both')
```

very successfully to obtain graphs with a tick at every unit like this:

[successful graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYvgp.png)

but then the same code is not working for this dataset and generates this graph, which ignores both conditions:

[unsuccessful graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z8Z6.png)

how can avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0))
```

If the units are just every integer, you could try replacing MaxNLocatior with MultipleLocator(base=1.0), as shown in the above code. Not sure why your current code does not work.

Comment: Hi!, no I can't put base 1 in the major locator too. Because some of the graphs go to 100 and then it gets too crowed.